# How to output Name in Matrix entries

Tags: matrix, output

I have matrix field set up, is that possible to output Name in Field Settings (refer to the handle: aggressiveBehavior)? Thanks

[image]

Comment: That's a crazy long field name! Seems like most of that should go under the "Instructions".

Comment: The client wants it to show the question as the title, not the instruction, that's why we put it in the name field. I guess we need a separated field to store it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must insist on using such a long field name rather than putting it in your twig template, then this code should work:

```
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('fieldName') %}

{% for blockType in field.getFieldType.getSettings.blockTypes %}
    {% if blockType == 'pet' %}
        {% for field in blockType.fields %}
            {% if field.handle == 'aggressiveBehavior' %}
                {{ field.name }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is not possible looking at the [Matrix Block Model Docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/matrixblockmodel).

What I would usually do, instead of having the front end facing title as the Field Name, is keep the Field name solely for the back end.

An example be (for a front end form)

```
<label>{{ 'Is your pet ever aggressive to strangers?' | t }}</label>
{% for option in matrixBlock.aggressiveBehavior.options %}
<input type="radio" name="aggressiveBehavior" value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}
{% endfor %}
```